# python while and if with pairs of conditions

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I can't figure out why this is not working, I've looked at how the "if any([])" syntax is used but in my case I have conditions that come in pairs.

I am trying to generate a random sequence of arrows where all combinations are allowed except the negation of the last arrow (so if the first arrow is L, then the next arrow cannot be R). The code should be keeping Ch2 = 0 if a disallowed sequence occurs and hence in the while loop, otherwise it should set Ch2 = 1 and then I can write code to move on to the next arrow in the sequence.

Also I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I am just learning Python.

```
Arrow_Array = ['L.png', 'R.png', 'U.png', 'D.png']
Ch2 = 0

Choice1 = random.choice(Arrow_Array)

while Ch2 != 1:
Choice2 = random.choice(Arrow_Array)
if any([Choice1 == 'L.png' and Choice2 == 'R.png', Choice1 == 'R.png' and Choice2 == 'L.png', Choice1 == 'U.png' and Choice2 == 'D.png', Choice1 == 'D.png' and Choice2 == 'U.png']):

    Ch2 = 0
else:
    Ch2 = 1
```

Comment: Define not working please. What's your error?

Comment: Code is not properly indented ?

Comment: Indent the codes after the  `while` statement.

Comment: The code still generates invalid sequences - so if the first arrow is "L" I still get scenarios where the second is "R" which is not supposed to happen.

Comment: The indentation didn't fix the problem but thanks for helping with format, still new to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, this function does what you want, I think:

```
import random

def get_arrow_seq(n):
    """
    Return a list of arrow filenames in random order, apart from the
    the restriction that arrows in opposite directions must not be
    adjacent to each other.

    """ 
    arrow_array = ['L.png', 'R.png', 'U.png', 'D.png']
    # Indexes of the arrows reversed wrt those indexed at [0,1,2,3]
    other_directions = [1,0,3,2]
    # Start off with a random direction
    last_arrow = random.choice(range(4))
    arrows = [arrow_array[last_arrow]]

    this_arrow = other_directions[last_arrow]
    for i in range(n):
        while True:
            # Keep on picking a random arrow until we find one which
            # doesn't point in the opposite direction to the last one.
            this_arrow = random.choice(range(4))
            if this_arrow != other_directions[last_arrow]:
                break
        arrows.append(arrow_array[this_arrow])
        last_arrow = this_arrow

    return arrows

print(get_arrow_seq(10))
```

For example:

```
['R.png', 'U.png', 'R.png', 'D.png', 'D.png', 'L.png', 'L.png',
 'D.png', 'D.png', 'D.png', 'L.png']
```

That is, pick a random integer index into your array of arrow image names and check it against the list of indices of reversed arrows, rejecting any matches. I've PEP8ed the variable names, etc, because I'm just not used to the capitals.